# Horizontal Scrollview inside ListView item?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` item layout that is using a `HorizontalScrollView` in the center. I have used the android attribute "`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`" on my parent `LinearLayout` so that the `ListView` items are still selectable.

The problem I am having is that when clicking the part of the `ListView` item which is the `HorizontalScrollView`, the `ListView` item click event is not called.

How can I get the click event of the `HorizontalScrollView` to call the `ListView` list item click event?

Comment: please use try catch blog surroung listview click event and print error in log and post ur error here so that we can exatcly know what's going wrong.

Comment: I do not have any errors... The issue is to do with the behavior of the views as they are setup in this way.

Comment: ok can u post ur xml file wich u r using as custom adatper?

Answer (score 1):

HorizontalScrollView  doesn't have **"onClick()"**, see this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

It support gestures and have **"onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)"**

So you can use it as click. See followin demo which I hav prepared.

```
//      Followin  code will not work  for HorizontalScrollView
        /*hsv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(HorizontalListActivity.this, tvMiddle.getText().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/

        hsv1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your Msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: With onTouch the event is fired for every touch? I still want to be able to scroll the HorizontalScrollView. Only in the case where the user clicks/taps the HorizontalScrollView do I want it to act with the normal listview item click behavior.

Comment: Pardon, I am not getting you properly. If you have time, can you explain me in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Adding boolean variables touchDown and touchUp to the adapter class as follows seems to work fairly well:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject>{
    ...
    //touch down + touch up with no other motion events in between = click
    boolean touchDown = false;
    boolean touchUp = false;
    private int iHostViewID;
    ...

    public MyListAdapter(Context context,int viewResourceId, List<MyObject> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        iHostViewID = viewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View itemView = convertView;

        //iff we cannot re-use a view
        if(itemView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (
            (LayoutInflater)hContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemView = inflater.inflate(iHostViewID, null);
        }

        final View hItemView = itemView;
        final int hPosition = pos;
        ...
        final HorizontalScrollView textDataSV = 
        (HorizontalScrollView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.widget_hsv);
        textDataSV.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                        touchDown = true;
                    }
                    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                        touchUp = true;
                     }

                    else{

                        touchDown = false;
                        touchUp = false;
                    }

                    if(touchDown && touchUp){
                        //click 
                        //mMyListView is the reference to the list view
                        //instantiated in the view controller class responsible
                        //for setting this adapter class as the list view's adapter
                        mMyListView.performItemClick(hItemView, hPosition, 
                        hItemView.getId());
                    }



                    return false;
                 }
         });
    }
}
```

It's far from perfect, but should work for most standard use-cases