# CustomListView onItemClickListener not working while using HorizontalScrollView, Infinitely called getView() method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, horizontalscrollview, custom-adapter

I am using the following code.
Adapter.java class

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private java.util.List<String> List;
    private Context context;
    public Adapter(List<String> list, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.row_item, list);
        this.List = list;
        this.context = ctx;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        NameHolder holder = new NameHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
            holder.topic_name = tv;
            holder.myLayout = ll;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (NameHolder) v.getTag();
       String topic = List.get(position);
       holder.topic_name.setText(topic);    
       ImageView imgUsers = new ImageView(context);
       imgUsers.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers);
       return v;
    }

    private static class NameHolder {
       public TextView topic_name;
       public LinearLayout myLayout;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    Adapter myAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
            list.add("Name"+i);
        }
        myAdapter = new Adapter(list, MainActivity.this);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"lets see"+list.get(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the expected output is a single image in every listItem, which tend to go to infinite.
And the onItemClickListener is not working as well.
Also, `onItemClickListener` works if we don't add `HorizontalScrollView`.
Writing `onClickListener()` in Adapter itself helps little as it works unpredictably.
Also, on adding a print statement in `getView()` and observing in Logcat, I find it difficult to understand the pattern in which `getView()` is called.
These are the problems I face. I require a working code of the things I wish to apply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Replace this code 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        NameHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new NameHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            holder.topic_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.myLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (NameHolder) convertView.getTag();

        String topic = List.get(position);
        holder.topic_name.setText(topic);
        ImageView imgUsers = new ImageView(context);
        imgUsers.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        holder.myLayout.removeAllViews();
        holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: But I am still not able to click on the portion where the the horizontal Scroll View is situated. Just this same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272918/horizontal-scrollview-inside-listview-item

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding an ImageView every single time here

```
ImageView imgUsers = new ImageView(context);
imgUsers.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers);
```

Why don't you include the ImageView as part of your list item layout?

Comment: I wish to add random number of images(in every listItem) in my real app to have the app as dynamic. Also, on just if we add around 10 images, and have HorizontalScrollView, onItemClickListener() still doesn't work. Also, if I do something like this :

Comment: if(!check.contains(List.get(position))){
       imgUsers.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers);
  check.add(List.get(position));
       }   where check contains names of those listItems in which I have inserted the image, but still it doesn't work and gives random results.